# Extend/Modify NHibernate classes at runtime

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, conform

Apologies if there's an on point answer already out there but I haven't found it. I'm using NH3 and I've got a use case where I want to add a Set onto any entity who's class implements a specific interface. I have a configuration builder class so I can make these changes before creating the session factory.

Given this reduced example:

```
public class Person : IHasExtraItems
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.ExtraItems = new HashSet<ExtraItem>();
    }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExtraItem> ExtraItems { get; protected set; }
}

public class ExtraItem
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And this example mapping:

```
  <class name="Person">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>
    <property name="Birthdate"/>
    <set name="Extra" table="PersonExtraItems" cascade="all">
      <key column="PersonId"/>
      <many-to-many column="ExtraItemId" class="ExtraItem" unique="true" />
    </set>
  </class>
```

Since I want to be able to apply this functionality to many classes transparently -- just by implementing the interface -- I don't want to put the "ExtraItem" in the mapping. Instead I want to add it at runtime. So if I remove the  property from the xml mapping, how can I add this at runtime?

There's this describing exactly the type of change I'm trying to make:
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/01/Dynamic-Mapping-with-NHibernate.aspx

But it doesn't map a many to many set, and my feeble brain has been unable to decipher the in-memory mapping representation nhibernate uses to create the effect. This is the closest I've come, based on trying to get properties visible in the debugger to match

```
foreach (var cls in cfg.ClassMappings)
{
    if (typeof(IHasExtraItems).IsAssignableFrom(cls.MappedClass))
    {
        NHibernate.Mapping.Property property = new NHibernate.Mapping.Property();
        NHibernate.Mapping.Set value = new NHibernate.Mapping.Set(cls);
        value.Role = cls.EntityName + ".ExtraItems";
        value.IsGeneric = true;
        var table = new Table();
        table.Name = cls.MappedClass.Name + "ExtraItems";
        value.CollectionTable = table;
        value.GenericArguments = new Type[] { typeof(ExtraItem) };
        value.IsOptimisticLocked = true;
        value.IsLazy = true;
        mappings.AddCollection(value);
        property.Value = value;

        property.Name = "ExtraItems";
        property.PersistentClass = cls;
        property.Cascade = "all";
        cls.AddProperty(property);
    }
}
```

In a test, this produces a runtime error because the key is null, however the XML mapped version works, and looks more or less identical at the time I'm making the changes.

**Bonus points**: I want a many-to-many specifically because I want a joined table. This lets me map an entity to the extending data with true foreign keys for performance. The ExtraItems should really be a value type rather than a true entity, but I couldn't figure out how to map that, even in XML.

**Bonus points, part 2:** Could I do this with confORM? I don't want to switch all my existing mappings to confORM, and I couldn't find an example of mixing confORM with conventional XML mappings, nevermind modifying existing mappings. Fluent would be another option, but I'm using NH3 and I don't think Fluent supports that yet.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** I'm fairly certain that my issue is that I'm not defining the elements of the set. However, I can't discern how to define the elements of the set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are builds of fluent for NH3, so you can use it (I do), and if you are using fluent you can very easily do this with a convention. You mention that in your bonus points section, so maybe you should give it another look?