# Error when creating a one-to-many association at runtime with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have situation where a few parts of my entity model is known only at runtime. In order to create queries in a simple way I'd like to add a simple `one-to-many` association on items referencing them before creating the `SessionFactory`.

I've looked at [this post in Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog/3294/dynamic-mapping-with-nhibernate) and [Extend/Modify NHibernate classes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894993/extend-modify-nhibernate-classes-at-runtime) but I'm stuck at an error saying:

> Unknown collection role: MySandbox.Parent.Children

What is a collection role and how do I instruct NHibernate to resolve it as if it was added in the hbm.xml?

### My test:

```
using (var tx = this.session.BeginTransaction())
{
    parent = new Parent() { Name = "Parent 1" };
    this.session.Save(parent);
    tx.Commit(); //<- The exception is thrown here
}
```

### My code for adding the association:

```
    // var cfg = <init nhibernate>

    PersistentClass cls = cfg.GetClassMapping("MySandbox.Parent");

    NHibernate.Mapping.Set value = new NHibernate.Mapping.Set(cls)
    {
        Role = cls.EntityName + ".Children",
        IsGeneric = true,
        GenericArguments = new Type[] { typeof(Child) }
    };

    NHibernate.Mapping.Property property = new NHibernate.Mapping.Property()
    {
        PropertyAccessorName = "noop",
        Value = value,
        Name = "Children",
        PersistentClass = cls
    };

    cls.AddProperty(property);
```

### My classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### The assocition mapping I'm trying to create at runtime:

```
<set name="Children" access="noop">
  <key column="ParentID" />
  <one-to-many class="MySandbox.Child, MySandbox"/>
</set>
```

It works perfect if I just create the association in the hbm.xml-file. I've also tried to compare a association created from xml with one created with the code above with no luck.

(Note: If I don't set the `Role`-property another exception of "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key" is thrown.)

Comment: i think role is the child type => `Role = typeof(Children).Name`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work; "Unknown collection role: MySandbox.Child"

Answer (score 0):

The error is because MySandbox.Child is not mapped. You need to map it (by creating a PersistentClass, etc) similar to how you did for the Parent class.

Comment: MySandbox.Child is mapped. Or do I have to add it some other way when creating the association aswell?

Comment: Both Parent and Child are mapped with hbm.xml-files as embedded resources. I didn't include them in my question for brevity.